# GridView thead, tbody, tfoot render order

Tags: asp.net, html, controls, rendering

Is there any way to control the order of which the GridView control renders it's `thead`, `tbody` and `tfoot` child elements?

According to W3C, the correct order is:

- thead
- tfoot
- tbody

The GridView control renders out:

- thead
- tbody
- tfoot

I am extending the GridView control, and I'm using the ["first column controls the width of all columns"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136851/table-layout-fixed-in-internet-explorer-breaks-large-tables) approach. But if the W3C specifications are not met (`thead` -> `tfoot` -> `tbody`) all hell breaks loose.

I've been reading up on this issue, and it seems that the GridView control has no support for this yet--it's planned though. Even so; I bet there must be some way to counter this sketchy implementation.

Any and all help apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not yet possible. Although Microsoft is planning this feature for a future release.

Answer (score 1):

If you need strict W3C Validation of your HTML (you must have a valid reason), you better not use ASP.net server controls, because you don't have any control on the HTML they generate.

I bet that this little problem is just the tip of the iceberg of the problems that you will find later.

Comment: Indeed, you cannot rely on server controls for semantic, valid HTML.  There's absolutely no guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that any HTML generated by a Microsoft class will 100% definitely break validation *and* only work with it's Internet Explorer.

Write your own implementation - or find some Open Source class that will take care of it properly.

Comment: "only work with it's Internet Explorer" that really not true.